# Extending Website UI to show third party content

Tags: javascript, user-interface

I have a website and want to make it extensible by allowing other developers to create UI widgets and show them up in my website. I am thinking to create an environment where the UI widgets can completely run on openwhisk serverless environment and these widgets can be embedded into my website. What would be the best way to include these UI widgets into my website. The primary things that i am considering are,

1. These widgets should not slow down my website
2. These widgets should not create security implications on my website
3. There should be a way to block/control these UI widgets

One possiblity that I am looking at is using iframe? Any other alternatives would be appreciated. Any reference links that has already achieved something similar would greatly help.

Thanks,